# search for tweets in a given time window in python

Tags: python, api, twitter

I want all tweets from May 2013 to May 2014 containing a given word.

I looked at the API documentation for [GET search/tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets), but it seems it doesn't allow you to give a time window, only a date and it will retrieve tweets up to 7 days before.

How can I retrieve those tweets in python? (Basically I want to write a script that does what the  [Twitter advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) does

Comment: You should try a few things first and then ask a more specific question on a problem that you may face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the The Twitter Search API documentation, the query you want is not possible: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets
>   published in the past 7 days.

Beyond the last 7 days, what you want to achieve can only be done through manually searching an account on Twitter.

You could try [twarc](https://github.com/edsu/twarc)
with the advanced search operators you referenced but I am not sure if it will query an entire year per the Twitter Search API documentation.

Although not Python based, one alternative would be to use https://webrecorder.io/

Scroll to the time you want to record or attempt to capture the entire feed. Note the auto scrolling option as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to dump your Twitter feed to JSON and parse it for the tweets you want. I just put this together for you in Python using the tweepy and json modules.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json


def process_or_store(tweet):
    converted = json.dumps(tweet)
    parsed = json.loads(converted)
    return parsed


access_token = ''
access_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
    j = process_or_store(tweet._json)
    m2013 = ['May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', '2013']
    m2014 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', '2014']

    if all(x in j['created_at'] for x in m2013):
        print "%s -- %s" % (j['created_at'], j['text'])
    elif all(x in j['created_at'] for x in m2014):
        print "%s -- %s" % (j['created_at'], j['text'])
```

Comment: I need tweets "in general", not mine. I am worried that there is no possibility to get them without accessing a timeline, am I right? 
I have no users, the only parameters I can use as filters are the language (italian), the time window (May 2013-May 2014) , and the keywords associated to the concept I'm interested in to build my statistics.
Thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: api.user_timeline int he above code can be altered to get other users tweets. Be careful, their API has a request timer per hour that will lock you out for a little while if you start getting too big. import tweepy and do a dir(tweepy) to see all the methods you can use. Also, a good Google search will get you to the documentation. Their examples page is pretty well written.